# Algebras where all indecomposable modules are rigid

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Is there a classification of selfinjective algebras having $Ext^{1}(X,X)=0$ for every indecomposable module X?
Examples include trivial extensions of representation-finite hereditary algebras.
One might assume algebraically closed field and Im mostly interested in a classification up to stable equivalence then.

Comment: The might or might not be such a classification, but it's worth asking.   One instance which makes me a bit skeptical is the case of the group algebra in the defining prime characteristic of a finite group of Lie type.    While the algebra itself is well-behaved, there are isolated special cases in which a simple module can have nontrivial self-extensions, e.g., finite symplectic groups.     Aside from this, there are many selfinjective algebras whose indecomposables are mostly unknown.   So it's not easy to visualize a classification of the type you ask about.

Comment: Hmm, actually I expect any such algebra to be representation-finite. For group algebras the answer is then (in case this is true) easy: A block has this property iff it is stable equivalent to a Brauer tree algebra with multiplicity one. Another interesting question might be to restrict to simple modules with this property.

Comment: [Small typo: My first word should have been "There".]    Concerning your comment, keep in mind that the group algebra of a finite group often fails to be representation-finite even when your Ext condition is satisfied by *simple* modules.    Maybe restate your question in a little more detail and with more examples?

Comment: The condition on simples isnt so interesting I think, since its not invariant under derived or stable equivalence. So Im mostly interested in a classification up to stable equivalence and one might assume the field to be algebraically closed. I added this.